# Java: Convert List<Object> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, dictionary

I am currently getting data from database like so:

```
Model---Year
aaaaa---2010
aaaaa---2011
aaaaa---2012
bbbbb---2010
bbbbb---2011
```

I am getting this data through SQL statement, getJdbcTemplate, and ResultSet. Then storing it in a list of value object:

```
List<ModelAndYear> modelYearList = new ArrayList<ModelAndYear>();
```

My ModelAndYear class is this:

```
public class ModelAndYear{
   private String model;
   private String year;

   public String getModel() {
       return model;
   }
   public void setModel(String model) {
       this.model= model;
   }
   public String getYear() {
       return year;
   }
   public void setYear(String year) {
       this.year= year;
   }
```

How do I take the populated modelYearList who's data will be in the format of:

```
aaaaa,2010
aaaaa,2011
aaaaa,2012
bbbbb,2010
bbbbb,2011
```

and sort it into the format of

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

so data will be in the format of:

```
aaaaa,<2010,2011,2012>
bbbbb,<2010,2011>
```

I do not have an idea where to start.

I have:

```
Map<String, List<String>> newModelYearList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for(int i=0; i < modelYearList.size(), i++){
           //sorting will occur here i think?     
           //how do i program the action of getting model from list 1 and checking if it exists in list 2?
        }
```

Comment: This seems very intuitive to do. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I have, just didn't put forth the things I have tried.

I've tried setting a for loop so for each element in my list, I will set the value to a second list with Map<String,List<String>> type. Then I tried checking to see if it exists in second list using ArrayList.indexOf, but didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should post it to show that you put effort in resolving the problem and explain where you're being stuck.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have Java 8 you can do this in a single pass using streams.

What you're essentially trying to do is a `groupBy` function, but also applying a `map` on top of that.  The following is what you're looking for (lots of indents added for clarity):

```
Map<String, List<String>> yearsByModel = 
    modelYearList
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                may -> may.getModel(),        
                Collectors.mapping(may -> may.getYear(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to just give the code, you should try to do it sourself.

Here is what you should do:

1. create a new map with a string and the list, just like you want it, eg call it result
2. loop through every element in your modelYearList
3. get the module and check if the result map already contains the key with the same module string
4. if so, get the list stored with the module, and add the year
5. if not, create a new list of type string and add the year, and store it in result with the module name

Note: i will use HashSet and HashMap, but you can use List and Map too if you want

```
HashSet<ModelAndYear> myl = new HashSet<>();
//Add all the ModelAndYear classes that you have
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for(ModelAndYear m : myl) //loop through every element in myl; this loop only works for lists, but makes it easier than loop with a counter in loop counting to the size of the list
    String model = myl.getModel(); //get the model
    if(result.containsKey(model)){ //did we already put a list in the result map for the model?
    result.get(model).add(m.getYear()) //add the year to the existing list in result map for the model
}else{
HashSet<String> newList = new HashSet<String>(); //create new list
newList.add(m.getYear()); //add the year
result.put(model, newList); //Store the list in the results
}
```

Comment: If possible, could you expand on step 3? I have put what I have so far at the ending of my post. How do I get the module? Sorry, am beginner.

Comment: You get the name of the module as a string from your class. Than you put an if case, checking if your result map already contains the same module:  if (resultMap.containsKey(moduleString)) { step 4 } else { step5 }

Comment: Okay, wait ill put the code at the end of my answer, but im on my phone so it could take a few minutes

Comment: When you refer to module, you mean the "model" attribute in my ModelAndYear class correct?

Comment: Okay, please take your time.

Comment: Note that this code is not tested and i hope it doesnt contains errors

Comment: This is more than I could have ever expected. Thank you for going above and beyond. If I could give you more rep I would :) I will work from this, thank you.

Comment: No problem, have fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code give you the result map as per the requirement:

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = 
                modelYearList
                    .stream()
                    .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                ModelAndYear::getModel,        
                            Collectors.mapping(ModelAndYear::getYear, Collectors.toList())));
        
        resultMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k +" : "+ v.toString()));
```