# Merge list of Objects by property

Tags: java, java-stream

I have been searching around different groupBy and stream threads but cannot find the answer to my problem. Basically I have this object:

```
public class Object {
    string name;
    string type; 
}
```

And I return a list of these from the database. What I would like to then do is iterate through the list of objects and remove duplicate names and save a list of the second properties under one object, in a new object that looks like this:

```
public class NewObject {
    String name;
    List<String> types;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34188593/16688813

Comment: I understand you don't want to remove duplicates but actually merge them right? Do you want to end up with a `List<NewObject>`?

Comment: @dajavax, yes that's correct! I am trying to merge them and end up with `List<NewObject`

Comment: In my answer I just added an example of how to make your own custom collector if you are interested in learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

- use groupingBy to create a map of `name, List of type`
- use the entryset of the map to create the new object.

I added the appropriate constructors and getters in the classes.

```
List<OldObject> list = ...
    
List<NewObject> newList = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OldObject::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(OldObject::getType,
                        Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new NewObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .toList();
    
}


class OldObject {
    String name;
    String type;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}


class NewObject {
    String name;
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public NewObject(String name, List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

For your added enjoyment, I thought I would also offer the following:

- create the map
- conditionally create a new object if the name key is not present
- in either case, add the type to the list instance  of the `NewObject` instance in the map which is returned by the `computeIfAbsent` method.

When finished, just assign the values to your Collection.

```
Map<String, NewObject> map = new HashMap<>();
for (OldObject ob : list) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(ob.getName(),
            v -> new NewObject(ob.getName(),
                    new ArrayList<>()))
            .add(ob.getType());
}
Collection<NewObject> newLista = map.values();
```

Caveats:

- values returns a Collection, not a list so you would need to use that or pass the Collection to a list constructor of some sort (e.g. ArrayList).
- the requires the addition of a add method in the `NewObject` class.
- you could also have a getter that returns the type list directly and do.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(ob.getName(),
            v -> new NewObject(ob.getName(),
                    new ArrayList<>()))
            .getTypeList().add(ob.getType());
```

Check out these additions to the [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction))

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't want to remove duplicates but actually merge them.

I replaced your `Object` class name with `OldObject` to avoid confusion with the actual Java `Object` class.

### Collecting to Map<String, List<String>> and then converting to List<NewObject>

You could write your own `Collector` (see later in the answer), but the easiest way of writing what you need would be to use the current `groupingBy` and `toList` `Collector`s and then using the resulting `Map` and create your `newObject` instance based on it to then again collect to a new List:

```java
oldObjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OldObject::getName, Collectors.mapping(OldObject::getType, Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        // Assuming a NewObject constructor that receives a String name and a List<String> types
        .map(e -> new NewObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Custom Collectors

If you are interested in learning how to make your own `Collector`, I made an example using a custom `Collector` as well:

```java
oldObjectList.stream().collect(Collector.of(
        // Supplier
        () -> new ConcurrentHashMap<String, NewObject>(),
        // Accumulator
        (map, oldObject) -> {
            // Assuming a NewObject constructor that gets a name and creates a new empty List as types.
            map.computeIfAbsent(oldObject.getName(), name -> new NewObject(name)).getTypes().add(oldObject.getType());
        },
        // Combiner
        (map1, map2) -> {
            map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> {
                v1.getTypes().addAll(v2.getTypes());
                return v1;
            }));
            return map1;
        },
        // Finisher
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())
));
```

You can even combine `groupingBy` and a custom `Collector` as a merge function:

```java
new ArrayList<>(oldObjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OldObject::getName, Collector.of(
        // Supplier
        // Assuming a NewObject constructor with no arguments that creates a new empty List as types.
        NewObject::new,
        // Accumulator
        (newObject, oldObject) -> {
            newObject.setName(oldObject.getName());
            newObject.getTypes().add(oldObject.getType());
        },
        // Combiner
        (newObject1, newObject2) -> {
            newObject1.getTypes().addAll(newObject2.getTypes());
            return newObject1;
        }
))).values());
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to create `NewObject` instances immediately and append types as necessary within the merge function.

Assuming that there `NewObject` has custom constructor and overridden `toString` method:

```java
class NewObject {
    String name;
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();

    public NewObject(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.types.add(type);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ name: " + name + "; types: " + types + "}";
    }
}
```

and that there are helper methods to create an instance of `NewObject` from `OldObject` and merge types of two `NewObject` instances:

```java
// MyClass
public static NewObject createNewObject(OldObject oo) {
    return new NewObject(oo.getName(), oo.getType());
}

public static NewObject mergeTypes(NewObject no1, NewObject no2) {
    no1.getTypes().addAll(no2.getTypes());
    return no1;
}
```

The transformation may be implemented as follows:

```java
List<OldObject> input = Arrays.asList(
    new OldObject("n1", "type1"), new OldObject("n1", "type2"),
    new OldObject("n2", "type1"), new OldObject("n3", "type2"),
    new OldObject("n1", "type3"), new OldObject("n2", "type2")
);

List<NewObject> result = new ArrayList<>(
        input
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                OldObject::getName,
                MyClass::createNewObject,
                MyClass::mergeTypes,
                LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
            ))
            .values());
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
{ name: n1; types: [type1, type2, type3]}
{ name: n2; types: [type1, type2]}
{ name: n3; types: [type2]}
```